# Сильные и слабые стороны MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется веб проект, в скором времени ожидается шквал запросов. Так же имеется дикое желание вести лог всех обращений, и даже больше, для дальнейшего анализа. Использовать сторонние средства не хотим.

Данные, согласитесь, не очень громоздкие: пара строковых полей, дата/время, идентификатор, да множественное поле. Поэтому для хранения решили использовать MongoDB в связке с django. Сложного совершенно ничего нет, но волнует все же вопрос, насколько хорошо справится этот представитель No-SQL решений с поставленной задачей?

Хочется узнать, может, кто проводил уже анализ под шквалом запросов? Может где описаны сильные и слабые стороны MongoDB? Насколько целесообразно, в свете дальнейшей обработки данных, использовать именно это решение вместо, например, PostgreSQL? У реляционных БД один существенный минус - отсутствие возможности создавать множественные поля, что чревато связями один-ко-многим и многие-ко-многим, а это может неблагоприятно сказаться на производительности, которая в свою очередь очень критична.

**UPD**

Суть задачи состоит в том, чтобы собирать все передвижения пользователя по нашим страничкам попутно отправляя эту статистику на наш сервер. Реализовано это на jQuery. С каждой страницы будет отправляться от 3 до 7 запросов, количество пользователей в сутки по прогнозам составит от 1 000 000. Что, скорее всего, говорит о том, что БД будет узким местом.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вот мерси:) не заметил.

Comment: Вы сами, на самом деле, частично ответили на свой вопрос...

С т.з. выборки большего профита не получите (если без учета join и т.д. Если их учитывать - получите и довольно ощутимый), с т.з. вставки получите очень серьезный прирост если не будете юзать SQL схему PK AI

К тому-же `alter table` - это ужас летящий на крыльях ночи :D

Соответственно, при каком-либо изменении вам не нужно страдать над структурой БД, вы просто делаете то, что вам нужно

PS: по поводу шквала запросов - все, как и раньше, решет кеширование и грамотные индексы

Comment: @AlexWindHope, кеширование не нужно, так как в том и задача, чтобы записать всё, совершенно любой запрос. Чтение из БД будет, скажем, раз в месяц для построения отчета. Значит, все же для быстрой и беспроблемной вставки, MongoDB хороша будет?

Comment: Если вы ждете креста на моем пузе - его не будет :)

Недостаточно хорошо описана задача, вообще, на мой взгляд, mongodb удобна, в первую очередь тем, что лишает многих проблем агрегации данных и проблем строгости 2d модели хранения данных ну и, как следствие, в их обновлении и вставке +, ИМХО, намного удобнее работать с концепцией документа в коде т.к. это лишает некоторого  геморроя ( по мнению автора комментария -  большего и страшного ) при работе с SQL субд

Comment: @AlexWindHope, добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование MongoDB может дать большой прирост тогда, когда вы по полной используете концепцию документа (по максимуму избавляетесь от join'ов и агрегации данных). Ответьте себе на вопрос - что именно вы хотите получить?

Если говорить о вставке данных - MongoDB побыстрее будет, учитывая объемы информации, это тоже достаточно важно. Если, к тому-же, для вашей задачи удобна концепция документа, тогда, безусловно, MongoDB будет отличным выбором.

Есть еще один фактор, а именно расширяемость Mongo, против этого, ничего толкового, SQL СУБД предложить не могут.

Так-же, в некоторых случаях, удобно то, что можно писать JavaScript код, который будет выполняться на стороне Mongo. (я знаю что в SQL, каг-бэ, тоже, можно, но, я думаю, никто не будет спорить с тем, что код выглядит ужасно и с тем, что это страшно)

Вообще, если вы до этого не работали с mongodb, (или работали, но на уровне Hello World) это, банально, очень интересный опыт, от которого, если есть возможность, на мой взгляд, не стоит отказываться.

Достоинства SQL я не описывал т.к., полагаю, вы с ними и так уже знакомы.

PS: Я постарался максимально адекватно оценить ситуацию, вообще mongodb, лично мне, очень нравиться, посему мой выбор был-бы очевидным

Вообще mongodb - няша, интересно то, что простое изменение SQL БД на noSQL полностью изменяет подход к разработке, мышление и т.д. и т.п.

Warning: MongoDB это не только БД, но и наркотик... Принимайте на свой страх и риск :D

Comment: Спасибо. У меня устойчивость к наркоте)

Comment: mongodb, и правда - няша, но не стоит забывать, что и няша может неожиданно превратиться в коварную тварь и вонзить нож в спину в самый неподходящий момент...это я про дырки( уязвимости ), которые, как мне кажется, не очень-то скоро пофиксят...

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB является достаточно популярной( и уверенно набирающей популярность ) системой управления базами данных в плане NOSQL решений. MongoDB в разы быстрее SQL СУБД( MySQL, MSSQL, например ). В высокопосещаемых проектах часто используется данная система управления БД. За примерами далеко ходить не нужно: Forbes, Disney, Yahoo...

**Вы пишете:**

```
...Поэтому для хранения решили использовать MongoDB в связке с django...
```

Умный подход к созданию высокопроизводительного сайта, но не стоит забывать стандартные действия, а именно:

```
Front-END Server: NGINX
Memcached Server( можно также попробовать производить кеширование стандартными 
                  средствами NGINX )
Не стоит забывать и о том, что кешировать лучше не все подряд, а лишь некоторые( динамичные ) области страницы.
```

---

**Но!** **MongoDB имеет ряд недостатков, о которых хотелось бы рассказать.**

Первый минус( неудобность ) - это то, что каждая NoSQL СУБД поддерживает уникальный( специфичный ) язык запросов, который каждый раз придется учить заново. Это же относится к MongoDB.

NoSQL СУБД( а в частности, MongoDB ) очень не устойчивы к разного рода атакам.
`Многие говорят про NoSQL: "Нет SQL - нет SQL Injection"`. Это верное утверждение. Несмотря на то, что закрывается один вид уязвимостей, так открывается целый ряд других:

```
Инъекции в регулярных выражениях.
JSON инъекции
JavaScript инъекции
```

---

Если интересно узнать, каким образом можно использовать данные уязвимости, то могу продемонстрировать.

---

Получив доступ через одну из потенциальных "дырок", злодей может делать крайне нежелательные действия:

```
Манипулировать REST-интерфейсом и подделывать межсайтовые запросы CSRF
Использовать регулярки в запросах
Выполнять скрипты на сервере( JS-Скрипты, например )

И это только часть...
```

---

**P.S**

Наверняка скоро в сети появится столько же инфы по защите от NoSQL-инъекций, как сейчас от простецких атак типа SQL Injection. Так, что решайте....

Comment: По поводу Front-End и Memcached (который вы написали с ошибкой) я достаточно знаю и видел, не говоря уже о том, что

1. Эту часть уже не изменить
2. Писал выше, что кешироваться ничего не будет

Будет отдельный модуль со своей логикой и своей БД для данной задачи. Насчет минусов, спасибо.

Comment: @Asen вся та ересь которую вы пишите справедлива только для архи-криворуких разработчиков. И связано все это с банальной проблемой - отсутствием нормальной обработки входящих данных. Более того, JavaScript инъекции возможно только тогда, когда разработчик просто напросто - идиот.

Жду примера где бы я смог увидеть какие-либо уязвимости не связанные с крикорукостью разработчика.

PS: хотя, как я понимаю, ваши знания здесь примерно такие-же, как в вопросе Node.JS, я думаю вы знаете о чем я.

PPS: надеюсь эту инфу вы взяли не из индусской статьи на хабре

Comment: - Любую информацию про перформанс нужно подтверждать ссылками. Конкретно в этом случае утверждение еще и оказывается враньем, потому что в каких-то сценариях [`MySQL-like` решения быстрее.][1]

- Утверждение про язык запросов тоже спорно, поскольку в промышленных решениях обычно на `raw` запросах ничего не реализовывается, а вся логика работы с БД делается поверх `ORM`-фреймворков. Поскольку та же самая `MongoDB` уже хорошо поддерживается большинством `ORM'ов`, то аргумент становится слабым.

[1]: http://labs.laulima.com/mongodb-vs-mysql-performance-benchmarks-cms/

Comment: @AlexWindHope, да нет, не из "индусской" статьи. Просто читал об этом достаточно, работал, непосредственно, с самой СУБД и т.д...

Comment: @Asen, скриптов, отличных от python, на сервере не будет. Запросы простейшие и только на запись пока, остальное будет скрыто от пользователя. CSRF отлично фильтруется django. Все приходящие данные в GET фильтруются снова же фреймворком, к тому же добавлю пару своих проверок.

**оффтоп**

@Asen, относитесь проще к критике, тем более если признаете знания этих людей.

Comment: @Dex, а здесь была критика?

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, теперь бы мне как-то протестить свое чудовище, под ДДОСом... или хотябы ДОСом... да еще и бенчмарк какой-то составить...

@Asen, печально, что вы ее не заметили. Поэтому просто, отнеситесь к написанному выше проще.

Comment: @Asen - ну вы написали много букафф о том, что MongoDB дырява, так вот - покажите хотя-бы один пример **не** из разряда:

    MongoDb.eval( incommingData );
    MongoDb.find({someProp: new RegExp( incommingData )})

Ну а если вы не умеете пользоваться инструментами которые вам предоставляют, то это не проблема самой бд.

К тому-же у вас был реальный опыт, так вот, покажите те куски кода, в которых можно увидеть уязвимость БД, а не вашего кода. Просто для того, что-бы не быть голословным (как в случае с Node.JS)

Comment: @Asen На деле, понятие "преступления" на форуме, вообще говоря, отсутствует *(за исключением того, что идет вразрез с правилами).* Вам же просто попытались показать, что используемые вами аргументы для сравнения либо спорны, либо слабо соответствуют постановке вопроса - если бы автора волновал вопрос идеологической безопасности NoSQL решений, то, я думаю, это было бы отражено в топике.

Comment: Ну, нет так нет....что уж)

Comment: и снова тишина... :D

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb не так проста, как может это показаться после первого изучения. Там есть много тонкостей и сюрпризов, таких как, например, возможная пропажа данных... Возможно, мой совет устарел (смотрю было написано в 2012 гг), но прежде чем применять её в продакшен, необходимо ознакомиться со всеми настройками, чтоб в последствии не было сюрпризов. Скорость просто-так из ниоткуда не возникает. Всегда приходится чем-то жертвовать.